# How to unambiguously express, as noun constructs, "dependent" and "dependee"?

Tags: compounds

- "dependent": the thing that depends on another
- "dependee": the thing
  that is depended upon

I was thinking 「依存しているもの」 and 「依存されているもの」.

While 「依存されているもの」 probably works to unambiguously mean "dependee", I can't shake the seeming ambiguity of 「依存しているもの」. I feel that 「依存しているもの」 could mean both "dependent" and "dependee", due to how Japanese verb+noun constructs work.

Comment: I guess there is no word that can be used for any situation where there are depender and dependee. What kind of context do you have in mind?

Comment: In software development. I have a database table to store the dependency relationships among a bunch of items - e.g. items A and B depend on item C, item D depends on items E and F. One column of the table is the ID of the dependent item, the other column is the dependee item, so that I effectively have "dependent" + "dependee" pairs. And I was looking for a succinct way to explain those columns in Japanese. I came up with 「〔依存している項目 + 依存されている項目〕のペア」.

Comment: If you put it in a pair, 依存している wouldn't look like dependee. I've never encountered such a list though. Most editors show something like 未解決の参照 or ライブラリ(etc)が見つかりません. Or possibly 依存元/参照元 and 依存先/参照先 work.

Comment: @sundowner Ah, so 依存元 would be the dependent, and 依存先 would be the dependee, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.